# Restoring full application state

Tags: angular, angular10

We have a large application which was not designed with ngrx (no stores, reducers etc') - which was a good trade-off decision at the time.
But now it received a feature request to save and restore state upon page refresh.
I know it can be done with ngrx, but I'm trying to avoid refactoring already complex architecture of a large app.

Tried researching for a solution to store to localstorage data from RouteReuseStrategy but it's impossible to save the current state.

I'll appreciate any ideas

Comment: Even with NGRX, you'll have to persist the data somewhere :)

Comment: @guzmanoj I don't mind persisting the data, I'm just looking for a solution which won't require to rewrite the entire state management architecture and currently out of ideas :-)